# How to make a container dependent on the height of one column and limit the other?

Tags: css

Here is where I'm at:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var height = document.querySelector("#content1").getBoundingClientRect().height;
  document.querySelector("#my_grid").style.height = height + "px";  
  setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1);
});
```

```css
#my_grid {
  display:grid;
  grid-template: "a b" auto /
              100px 100px;
  background-color:green;
  width:200px;
}

#col1 {
  grid-area:a;
  background-color:red;

}

#col2 {
  grid-area:b;
  background-color:yellow;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="my_grid">
  <div id="col1">
    <div id="content1">I want to set the height with my content!</div>
  </div>
  <div id="col2">I want to follow the height and spawn a scrollbar if I'm too short.</div>
</div>
<br><br>
<button>crappy JavaScript solution</button>
```

The amount of content in each column is dynamic.

I dislike the idea of running a timeout loop for style purposes.

I'd really rather not place the slave column inside the master column structurally since it would require major amounts of rewriting.

Is there a CSS solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're open to a solution that does not use `css` grids, here's one with `absolute` positioning.

```css
#my_grid {
  position: relative;
  background-color:green;
  width:200px;
}

#col1 {
  background-color:red;
  width: 100px;
}

#col2 {
  background-color:yellow;
  overflow:scroll;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="my_grid">
  <div id="col1">
    <div id="content1">I want to set the height with my content!</div>
  </div>
  <div id="col2">I want to follow the height and spawn a scrollbar if I'm too short.</div>
</div>
```